# How can I add items to named Tuple

Tags: c#, tuples

I have the following named list of Tuple

```
var tupleList = new List<(string SureName, string LastName, int Age)>();
```

How can I add items to that list using tupleList.Add ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var tupleList = new List<(string SureName, string LastName, int Age)>();
tupleList.Add(("a", "b", 3));
```

[image]

As you can see it demanded an item at the end of add, which seems to be optional and the reason for the double brackets.

Comment: I have no idea what the sentence *"As you can see it demanded an item at the end of add, which seems to be optional and the reason for the double brackets."* means. A better explanation is that `("a", "b", 3)` is the syntax for a 3-item tuble. By adding whitespace, we can see the syntax more clearly: `tupleList.Add( ("a", "b", 3) );`. Or we could split into two lines: `var tuple = ("a", "b", 3); tupleList.Add(tuple);`

Answer (score 0):

```
var tupleList = new List<Tuple<string, string, int>>();
tupleList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, int>("Nicolas", "Smith", 32));
```

Comment: That's using `Tuple` - the OP is asking about `ValueTuple`, despite the title. (A "named tuple" always ends up meaning ValueTuple.)

Comment: Additionally, providing documentation and an synopsis of said documentation can be very helpful to future readers in understanding *how* this solution works.